# Change Autoquery return type in DTO generation

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

I want to return a custom class from my custom AutoQuery endpoint that inherits `QueryResponse<T>` but adds a few extra properties.

```cs
public class WritingAssignmentBlogLookUpResponse : QueryResponse<BlogDto>, IResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string DebugMessage { get; set; }
}
```

But if I specify request like so:

```cs
[Route("/assignment/blogs/", "POST")]
public class WritingAssignmentBlogsLookUpRequest : QueryDb<Blog, BlogDto>, IReturn<WritingAssignmentBlogLookUpResponse>
{

}
```

Then the return type specified in generatd DTO for `client.post(req)` is `QueryResponse<BlogDto>` and it doesn't generate `WritingAssignmentBlogLookUpResponse` at all.

Do I just have to specify return type as `any` from my typescript service or is there a way to make the types match so I can strongly type it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t change [AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) responses which are already fixed in their service contract definition to return a `QueryResponse<T>`.

You can add extra info to the `Meta` Dictionary of the Response DTO (exists for this reason) otherwise if you need to change the Service Contract you’d need to convert it into a normal (I.e. non-AutoQuery) API which could use the [Service Gateway](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway) to call an existing AutoQuery API that decorates the response.